# Passing data from server to +page.svelt

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I found the answer after posting, but leaving this here for others because I spent 2 full days trying to figure this out.

The issue is that (let export data) data comes from the load function. A form returns data in (let export form) data. So I changed this:

```
    export let data;
    const { myDomain } = data;
```

To this to fix the issue and it works as expected:

```
    export let form;
    myDomain = form.data;
```

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I am trying to create a simple Sveltekit app that will take in a domain, search an API, and return JSON data about the company with that domain.

Below is my code. The console.log in the server code does return the POST data, but that data isn't getting passed back to `page.svelte`. The myDomain variable is undefined.

Any ideas?

**+page.svelte**

```html
<script>
    export let data;

    const { myDomain } = data;
</script>

<div class="centered">
    <h1>Company Info</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        <label>
            Search A Domain: 
            <input name="domain" autocomplete="off" />
        </label>
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    <h1>The company domain is {myDomain}</h1>
</div>
```

**+page.server.js**

```js
/** @type {import('./$types').Actions} */
export const actions = {
    default: async (event) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const body = await event.request.text();

        // Parse the request body
        body.split('&').forEach((pair) => {
            const [key, value] = pair.split('=');
            formData.append(key, decodeURIComponent(value));
        });

        // Access the domain field value
        const myDomain = formData.get('domain');

        console.log(myDomain);

        return {
           data: myDomain
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Better add an answer to your question and accept it, so it's directly visible that the problem is solved